# Fastest way to do $\int_{-1}^1 [(1-x^2)-x^2(1-x^2)] dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm a very lazy person and I always sum fractions wrong. I want to integrate if fast without having to expand this into a 4th degree expression:

$$\int_{-1}^1  (1-x^2)-x^2(1-x^2) dx$$

what would you do?

Comment: I would just expand it out to a simple polynomial. It really doesn't take that long

Comment: @Brenton I always makes silly mistakes during a test, I prefer the most symbolic integration possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The integrand is an even function and the integral is over a symmetric interval, then

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \left[ (1-x^2)-x^2(1-x^2)\right]\, dx&= 2\int_{0}^1(1-x^2)\left(1-x^2\right)\,dx\\
&=2\left[x-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5\right]_0^1
\end{align}

Comment: yes, I noticed that, but how would you finish it without expanding everything?

Comment: oh yes, the 0 part helps a lot, cuts in half the fractions needed to be summed

Answer (score 0):

With the way you've written it, there is no faster way other than to note that since only $x^2$ appears, the integral is equal to
$$2\int_0^1\left[1-2x^2+x^4\right]dx=2\left(1-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\right)=\frac{14}{15}.$$
Integrating polynomials often is best done by just using elementary methods, though in some situations you can make your life easier by recognizing symmetries, but *be careful when doing so*!